# How do I show the content of two entities in Firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use node.js with express.js and only show me the data of the book, but I also want to show the authors but I do not know how to do it.

Any ideas ?

Note :English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part

**My Controller :**

```
 'use strict'

var Libro = require('../models/libro');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');


const firebaseDb = admin.database();

function getLibros(req,res){
    firebaseDb.ref('libros').on('value',gotData,errData);
}

function gotData(data){
    console.log(data.val());
}
function errData(){
    console.log('TestErr');
}
```

**Result:**

```
{ '-LGeoSBuikhIuSicBH6I':    
     { 
       autor: '-LGc4ijGtUtQPoIyduOs',
       descripcion: 'Libro que trata sobre temas de memorias2 ',
       imagenRuta: 'assets/imagenes/HumbertoBallesteros.jpg',
       isbn: '978-958-42-6142-4',
       paginas: '200',
       precio: '50',
       titulo: 'Juego de Memoria'
     } 
}
```

**My database Firebase**

[Database Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY4MT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getLibros(req, res) {

    let todo_libros = []; // array of books

    // return Promise
    return firebaseDb.ref('libros').once('value')
        // libros es una array
        .then(libros => {
            let autor_promises = [];
            for (libro in libros) {
                todo_libros.push(libro); // libro
                autor_promises.push(firebaseDb.ref('autores').child(libro.autor).once('value')); // author
            }

            // Array de [autor]
            return Promise.all(autor_promises);
        })
        .then(autores => {
            for (let i = 0; i < autores.length; ++i)
                todo_libros[i].autor = autores[i];

            return null;
        })
        .then(() => {
            gotData(todo_libros);

            res.status(200); // send OK response
            res.json(todo_libros);

            return null;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            errData();
            console.log(err); // print error

            res.status(503); // Send Error Response
            res.send(err);
        })
}
```